# Is calling intValue() method required when getting an Integer value from Java HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, integer, autoboxing

I have a HashMap declared as:
`Map<Character, Integer> dict = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();`
In the code somewhere I am fetching the Integer value from the above map for a char. I observed if do not add the `.intValue()` method while getting the Integer value, the code terminates without any error and if I put the `intValue()` in the ** marked region it works fine.

Below is the complete code:

```
class Solution {
    public String minWindow(String s, String t) {
        int l =0, r = 0;
        Map<Character, Integer> dict = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        for(int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++){
            int count = dict.getOrDefault(t.charAt(i), 0);
            dict.put(t.charAt(i), count + 1);
        }

        int formed = 0;
        int required = dict.size();
        Map<Character, Integer> window = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        int[] ans = {-1, 0, 0};

        while(r < s.length()){
            char c = s.charAt(r);
            int count = window.getOrDefault(c, 0);
            window.put(c, count + 1);
            **if(dict.containsKey(c) && dict.get(c) == window.get(c)){
                formed++;
            }**
            while(l <= r && formed == required){
                if(ans[0] == -1 || r - l + 1 < ans[0]){
                    ans[0] = r - l + 1;
                    ans[1] = l;
                    ans[2] = r;
                }
                window.put(s.charAt(l), window.get(s.charAt(l)) - 1);
                if(dict.containsKey(s.charAt(l)) && window.get(s.charAt(l)) < dict.get(s.charAt(l))){
                    formed--;
                }
                l++;
            }
            r++;
        }
        return ans[0] != -1 ? s.substring(ans[1], ans[2] + 1) : "";

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Solution s = new Soultion();
        String ret = s.minwindow("ABCDEF", "BCD");
        System.out.print(ret);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dict.get(c) == window.get(c)` is how you compare `int`(s); unfortunately you are comparing `Integer`(s). Calling `intValue` to force a primitive equality comparison is one option. Another is `dict.get(c).equals(window.get(c))`

Comment: Would doing something like `dict.get(c) - window.get(c) == 0` work with unboxing?

Comment: @MihirKekkar: It would. But why work around a performant equals() with a bad-performing unboxing?

Comment: @ChristianH.Kuhn Interesting, I didn't know unboxing had poor performance time.

Comment: But even if I compare Integers, the comparison automatically happens between the unboxed ```int(s)```, right? Why does the code terminate? Why a code like below works and not the above:


```Integer a = 5;
  Integer b = 6;
  if(a == b) {
   System.out.println("Yes");
  }
  else {
   System.out.println("No");
  }```
I guess both the conditions are same. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Ohh, Looks like I found an answer to my comment above. If this would have been:
```Integer a = new Integer(10);
Integer b = new Integer(10);
System.out.ptint(a==b); // output would be false```

I guess I was missing a major concept of JAVA language. Gosshhh! Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Pankaj and it is sill not that trivial `Integer a = 1000; Integer b = 1000; System.out.print(a == b);` will also output `false` (normally only 256 integers (-128 to 127 or so) are cached; for others a new instance must be created)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Woahh, that looks like a magic. I guess I can now trick people using that. :) Thanks!

Comment: documented at [valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)) which is *used* by compiler to do auto-boxing (`int` to `Integer`)